# Boost: copy_file fail with access denied but there are no permission problem

Tags: c++, boost-filesystem

I wrote the following routine in order to copy all files in a directory to a subdirectory
and then remove them, but I keep getting an access denied on the copy_fail which looks misleading to me. Paths are corrects, files exist and permission are not read-only in the destination directory just created.

Any suggestion how to hunt the source of the problem?

I tried to debug, but I don't have the boost::filesystem source code.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

```
void
moveConfigurationFileToSubDirectory()
{
 // TODO: Catch errors.

 boost::filesystem::path full_path( boost::filesystem::current_path() );

 // Create directory subdir if not exist
 boost::filesystem::path subdirPath(kSubdirectory);
    if ( !boost::filesystem::exists(subdirPath) )
 {
  PLog::DEV.Development(devVerbose, "%s: creating directory %s", __FUNCTION__, subdirPath.string());
  boost::filesystem::create_directories(subdirPath);
 } else
  PLog::DEV.Development(devVerbose, "%s: directory %s exist", __FUNCTION__, subdirPath.string());

 // Iterate through the configuration files defined in the static array
 // copy all files with overwrite flag, if successfully delete file (looks like there is not remove)
 for (int i = 0; i < kNumberOfConfigurationFiles; i++)
 {
  boost::filesystem::path currentConfigurationFile(kConfigurationFiles[i]);

  try
  {
   boost::filesystem::copy_file(currentConfigurationFile, subdirPath, boost::filesystem::copy_option::overwrite_if_exists);
   boost::filesystem::remove(currentConfigurationFile);
  }
  catch (exception& e)
  {
   PLog::DEV.Development(devError, "%s: exception - %s", __FUNCTION__, e.what());
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You have to specify the filename you want for subdirPath and not just the path.  boost's copy_file isn't smart enough to know that by specifying a directory name, you want the file to have the same name as the source.

Comment: Why isn't this marked as the answer? Helped me a lot, thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

What OS are running this on? If on Linux/Unix then have you considered permissions on directory holding your source files (you are removing currentConfigurationFile, this means that directory holding that file must have write permission)?

Comment: I'm on windows. I rewrote the same piece of functionality by using Windows API and it works. Does the destination argument need to be a file or a directory ? Thanks.